# Confirmation messages

Tags: icons, confirmation

For a newsletters management page, when the user subscribes to a newsletter and clicks on the relative icon to subscribe (in this case an empty circle), is it necessary to push a pop up message confirming the subscription like “you have successfully subscribed to 1 newsletter” or a simple animation (the empty circle will be replaced from a loading one and finally with a checked circle) could be enough to communicate to the user that he correctly subscribed to the newsletter?

I think the alert would slow down the action of the user to subscribe also to other newsletters, since he would have to wait for the alert to disappear or he could still subscribe to others NL but with a list of confirmation alerts popping up on the screen.

I was thinking to show alerts just in case of error

Comment: Are you circling back to the server to confirm receipt of the subscription? Is that why the loading animation? In other words, there's some delay between user action and confirmation? If so, then, generally, simply changing the loading image to a checked circle upon server confirmation is the least intrusive yet sufficiently confirming, while the user continues with other activities on the page. Of course mission critical tasks likely need more attention.

Answer (score 1):

It is important to give the user a feedback of an action. This feedback does not have to be in form of text. What you mentioned with the animation of the CTA could be sufficient.

You also could communicate the success with a snack bar [Snack Bar](https://material.io/components/snackbars). This way, the user receives the notification without being prevented from completing the next task.

So in short: communicate the success of the newsletter subscription without getting in to the way of the users next steps.